# React native Native module RCTBubblingEventBlock is null

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Trying to create a callback from a Native module but the call back is not being fired. The code to call the native module seems to be working fine and it opens the scanning app but can't seem to get the callback to work at all

Here is my code.

```
@objc (ScanImageView)

class ScanImageViewController: UIViewController, ScanningViewControllerDelegate {

  @objc var onImageCapture: RCTBubblingEventBlock?

  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }

  @objc func startScan(){
    print("What had I created")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.getTopMostViewController()?.present(ScanningViewController(delegate: self), animated: true)
    }
  }

  func getTopMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {

    var topMostViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

    while let presentedViewController = topMostViewController?.presentedViewController {
      topMostViewController = presentedViewController
    }
    return topMostViewController
  }

  func scanningViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: ScanningViewController)   {
    print("Dismiss called")
    controller.dismiss(animated: true)
  }

  func scanningViewController(_ controller: ScanningViewController, didScan pointCloud: SCPointCloud) {
    print("scanningViewController called")
    print("scanningViewController called")
    if(self.onImageCapture != nil)
    {
      let event = ["startTime": "testing"]
      self.onImageCapture!(event)
      controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code for RCT_EXPORT_METHOD() macro:

```
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "React/RCTViewManager.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ScanImageView, UIViewController)
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(startScan)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(onImageCapture, RCTBubblingEventBlock)
@end
```

The .js file just has a button which on click calls startScan method and that seems to be working fine.

```
<button
    onPress={this.turnOn}
    title="Turn ON "
    color="#FF6347" 
    onImageCapture={this._onImageCapture}/>
```

The onImageCapture that is not being called at all. I have been trying for the past 5 hours. Can anyone please direct me in the right direction as to how to get the callback to work for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using sendEvent(withName: "", body: []) function. Had to make the following changes to my code

```
class ScanImageViewController: UIViewController, ScanningViewControllerDelegate
```

Changed above to

```
class ScanImageViewController: RCTEventEmitter, ScanningViewControllerDelegate
```

Also had to add in

```
@objc
  override func supportedEvents() -> [String]! {
    //Event names
    return ["onImageCapture", "onImageCompleted"]
  }
```

On the .js file you need to add in a handler to listen for the events

```
ScanImageEvents.addListener('onImageCompleted', ({ imageData }) => {
      console.log('onImageCompleted')
    })
```

Hope this helps someone